# System/Console Beep delayed after (re)booting the system

Tags: windows-7, boot, system-sounds, windows-embedded-7

I have a specific system where, whenenver I try to generate a Beep after a system reboot, it takes between 5 and 20 seconds for the first beep comes through.

The System I see this behavior in is an Embedded Windows 7. I attempted to generate the System beep using two different means:

- Opening Console and pressing Ctrl+G and Enter
- Executing Console.Beep(); in a C#-Program.

If most services on the machine are set to a delayed start, the waiting time for the first beep is close to 20 seconds. If I set every service on immediate start (and waiting several minutes after logon), the delay goes down to about 5 seconds.

Is there anything I can check or do to reduce this delay to zero? Putting a program into Autostart/Startup that beeps first so it's initialized is not a valid solution I really want to accept. Google has been a bit bad at giving results on this topic for me.

Comment: Your question does not make since.  What does a C# program playing a sound have to do with rebooting the system?

Comment: That's why I am stumped. It seems something is not initialized when (re)booting the system, hence makes the Console.Beep delay the beep for up to 20 seconds.

Comment: Trying booting into a minimal boot configuration.